# Embedded mysql server and application size

Tags: mysql, c

Sorry if this is too stupid but I couldn't resist asking.
I wish to create a  C application with an embedded MYSQL database **(libmysqld)** in it.
What I am confused about is the size of the application.
Since the application itself embeds a mysql db in it, would the size of the application be the size of the binary(excluding db) + size of the embedded db?
If this is the case wouldn't it be difficult run standalone applications which
deals with large volumes of mysql data as they would consume a lot of RAM?

Am I missing the concept here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Embedding mysql means embedding the "server" code, not data. Database tables will be stored in configured datadir.

Comment: Okie Dokie !! I'm somewhat beginning to understand the concept. :)